# Checker Framework passing @Initialized value as @UnderInitialization parameter

Tags: java, checker-framework

Using the [Checker Framework](https://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html), methods used by the constructor can take `@UnderInitialization` annotated parameters.

Calling such a method from a non-constructor and passing it an `@Initialized` parameter results in the following error:

```
error: [argument.type.incompatible] incompatible types in argument.

found   : @Initialized <Object>
required: @UnderInitialization <Object>
```

I'm not sure that this is a problem since passing an `@Initialized` value shouldn't have ill side effects.

What is the proper way to address this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type-checking warning looks right to me.

To understand the issue, consider the [type hierarchy of the initialization type system](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html#initialization-qualifiers).
[`@Initialized`](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/api/org/checkerframework/checker/initialization/qual/Initialized.html) and [`@UnderInitialization`](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/api/org/checkerframework/checker/initialization/qual/UnderInitialization.html) are siblings in the type hierarchy.  It is no more legal to supply `@Initialized` when `@UnderInitialization` is required than it is to supply a `List` when a `Date` is required.

If your method works for both values that are initialized and for values that are under initialization, then you could annotate its parameter as [`@UnknownInitialization`](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/api/org/checkerframework/checker/initialization/qual/UnknownInitialization.html) which is a supertype of both `@Initialized` and `@UnderInitialization`.